# Как изменить ширину регулировки звука в теге audio?

Tags: html, css, аудио

Как изменить ширину регулировки звука в теге audio?

```
<audio src="assets/music/kuzmin.mp3" controls=""></audio>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, о каком изменении идет речь....

Comment: в вопросе добавил скрин

Comment: Тебе придется самому с нуля делать, если используешь тег  `audio`

Comment: и уже без тега `аудио` обойтись...  используй объект `new Audio`

Comment: Для кастомного плеяка это рояли не играет, стандартную панель можно скрыть.